# Making discounts gives error on payment gateway

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugins, payment-methods

When i applied discounts, [my payment gateway](https://dev.iyzipay.com/en/checkout-form/initialize) gives an error. It says that *Basket items price must be greater than zero*. Here is the section that takes items in cart:

```
// Add items
    $basketItems = [ ];
    $items       = $this->getItems();

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $basketItem = new \Iyzipay\Model\BasketItem();
        $basketItem->setId("item:" . $item->getName());
        $basketItem->setName($item->getName());
        $basketItem->setCategory1("Category1");
        $basketItem->setCategory2("Category2");
        $basketItem->setItemType(\Iyzipay\Model\BasketItemType::PHYSICAL);
        $basketItem->setPrice('' . ($item->getPrice() * $item->getQuantity()));

        array_push($basketItems, $basketItem);
    }

    $request->setBasketItems($basketItems);
```

Without discounts plugin works fine. I can get payments.

One additional thing is; that payment gateway accepts two basket amount as [price and paidPrice](https://dev.iyzipay.com/en/checkout-form/initialize#request) which is total amount of basket and final amount(tax+discount+sale...) respectively. But when i look at my plugin this amount is set as same:

```
public function getData ()
{
    $card = $this->getCard();

    $amount = '' . $this->getAmount();

    $email     = $card->getEmail();
    $firstName = $card->getFirstName();
    $lastName  = $card->getLastName();
    $fullName  = $firstName . ' ' . $lastName;

    $billingAddress = $card->getBillingAddress1() . ' ' . $card->getBillingAddress2();
    $billingCity    = $card->getBillingCity();
    $billingCountry = $card->getBillingCountry();

    $shippingAddress = $card->getShippingAddress1() . ' ' . $card->getShippingAddress2();
    $shippingCity    = $card->getShippingCity();
    $shippingCountry = $card->getShippingCountry();


    $request = new \Iyzipay\Request\CreateCheckoutFormInitializeRequest();
    $request->setLocale(\Iyzipay\Model\Locale::TR);
    $request->setPaymentGroup(\Iyzipay\Model\PaymentGroup::PRODUCT);
    $request->setCurrency('TRY');
    $request->setConversationId('' . $this->getTransactionId());
    $request->setPrice($amount);
    $request->setPaidPrice($amount);
    $request->setCallbackUrl($this->getReturnUrl());
```

Shouldn't be the price and paidPrice be different? May be these two are not related but i want to mention.